# java, object pool: make object unusable after it is returned to the pool?

Tags: java, pool

I am writing an SshConnectionPool, which stores and returns SshConnections. The idea is that a user should do something like this:

`SshConnection sc = SshPool.getInstance().getConnection(server, user, password, port);
// use connection in some way
SshPool.getInstance().release(sc);`

And after that I want the `sc` reference to be unusable. I know I can't set it to null in the implementation of the `release()` method. But how can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you implement a factory instead and make your `SshConnection` implement `Closeable`?

Comment: @fge Because I want to be able to reuse the objects from the pool, that is, when one user has released a session back to the pool, another one can get that same session.

Comment: Why? Object pooling makes close to no sense in 2014. Also, an SSH connection is not like a database connection, it is not (easily) reusable.

Comment: if u write sc= null in ur code alone that will make sure u cant use the sc referrence to the same object.//

Comment: @fge The point is that connecting to servers via ssh does take some time, in the system i work on that happens quite a lot, and i want to save some time. On the other hand, i want to do several things on the same server in parallel, and i don't want other devs to make the mistake of passing the same ssh connection to a process while it is being used in a different process.

Comment: @fge I think that is a over-generalisation. I have found significant performance boosts from reusing huge arrays. You certainly don't want to start with it but after profiling object reuse can make sense (whether it does in this case is a seperate question)

Comment: @RichardTingle "close to"; but yes, I over generalized. In this case though I don't really see the point. Anyway, I have proposed a solution... This is sort of what I use in java7-fs-ftp for data transfers (I can't liberate the FTP client until the transfer is done)

Answer (score 2):

No idea how you will "reuse" `SshConnection` objects but anyway, my suggestion is that you:

- add a parameter to its constructor which is the `SshPool` itself;
- make the `SshConnection` object implement `Closeable`, and in `.close()`, give the object back to the pool.

As in:

```
private final SshPool pool;

SshConnection(final SshPool pool, other parameters)
{
    this.pool = pool;
    // etc
}

@Override
public void close()
    throws IOException
{
    pool.release(this);
    // other instructions here
}
```

This means among other things that you'll be able to use such objects in a try-with-resources statement; and the only requirement on the user of the API is that they `.close()` once used, which they should do anyway for any `Closeable` object.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the question correct..then u need to make the class as immutable

with that the object instance will be usable by the variable but for any change the object will be discarded and a new instance will be created

[how to make immutable](http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/10/28/how-to-make-a-java-class-immutable/)

Answer (score 0):

For the brave who will someday follow my footsteps:

What I did eventually was: I declared the `SshSession` as an interface and created 3 implementations of it: a real/live/working session (`RealSession`) which has all functionality, the variables are set to real values and methods do real work (e.g. `exec(String command)` will execute a command on a remote machine), a dummy session (`DummySession`) which has all the ivars, but throws exceptions when "doing" methods are called (e.g., it returns real host name on `ssh.hostname()`, but throws an exception on `ssh.exec(command)`, and a session wrapper that has an `SshSession` implementation within it and all the methods in the session wrapper call the corresponding methods on the wrapped session.

The `SshPool` stores within it a map of `RealSession`s, but returns a `SessionWrapper` with a `RealSession` wrapped into it. So outside of the pool you can only deal with `SessionWrapper`s. Thus, when you call `pool.release(sessionwrapper)`, the pool returns the session from the wrapper into the pool, and puts a `DummySession` into the wrapper. That way you can still access the info about the session (e.g. host, user, etc), but cannot call any methods on it.

I know some code would not go amiss, but I hope the description is clear enough.